# Laravel Redirection of Images with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, laravel, .htaccess, redirect

My server cannot live under the root directory for my laravel install so i have a redirect on test.com to test.com/public.

I need a quick fix for images, currently the path is `public/home/slider/slide-1.jpg` but needs to be `public/storage/home/slider/slide-1.jpg` so basically need to just append the storage directory name. Does anyone know how to do this with htaccess?

Comment: How do you get the image path?

Comment: I use the {{ asset('/') }}

Comment: Just do: `{{ asset('/storage/home/slider/slide-1.jpg') }}`

Comment: Its already in all my views etc, basically trying to push to production..

Comment: Then it means it works?

Answer (score 0):

If you just created a new subfolder inside the public folder, why don't use the default Laravel `asset()` helper with the new subfolder?

If you was using before:

```
{{ asset('/home/slider/slide-1.jpg') }}
```

Just add the `storage` top folder on it:

```
{{ asset('storage/home/slider/slide-1.jpg') }}
```

Comment: This is not appropriate as there is a git repo, and so htaccess would be only viable and on the production server